# Docker: Add Docker Files to Workspace..... I don't have this option

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile

I'm learning and trying according to the tutorial
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python#_add-docker-files-to-the-project
[Add Docker files to the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3VEw.png)

[I cant find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Iqq.png)

Why don't I see this option?

I installed the add-on correctly on fresh Visual Studio Code ,I have installed the latest Visual Studio Code and the correct current plugins

Comment: On the screenshot you provide it seems like you already have a `Dockerfile` open. It may be that the extension that holds this command command detects that you already have the correct files, although this behaviour seems undocumented. If you created them manually, try deleting them, refresh your VSCode window and search for the command again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.